# Moving filenames of images to a text file

Tags: linux, files, cat

I have images in a folder where the the name of each image is `img1.jpg`, `img2.jpg`, etc. and the locations of the images are of the form  `/home/master/test/data/obj/img1.jpg`,  `/home/master/test/data/obj/img2.jpg`, etc.
I am trying to extract the paths of the images and put it in a text file called `sample.txt` where each line corresponds to the image location:

```
/home/master/test/data/obj/img1.jpg
/home/master/test/data/obj/img2.jpg
```

Is there an easy way to do this in linux?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility with [`find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)

```
find /home/master/test/data/obj/ -type f -name "*.jpg" > sample.txt
```

It returns the absolute pathname of the `*.jpg` files contained in `/home/master/test/data/obj/`.

The `find` command and its option `-type` and `-name` are in the POSIX specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have them with full path you can use

```
ls -1 /home/master/test/data/obj/*.jpg >sample.txt
```

If you already in to the directory you can use:

```
ls -1 $(pwd)/*.jpg >sample.txt
```

Comment: @RomeoNinov: I want the complete path of the images in a text file along with the name of the images. As simple as that,

Comment: @guest232323, please check my edited answer

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Is that the number 1 or letter 'l'?

Comment: @guest232323, this the number 1 (in `ls` mean one per line)

Comment: @RomeoNinov: If I am already in the directory with the images, can I just put ls -1 *.jpg >sample.txt?

Comment: @guest232323, if you are already in to the directory you can use result of command `pwd` to get the full path. Check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
cd your_dir
find "$(pwd)" -type f -name "img[0-9]*\.jpg" -exec echo > sample.txt {} \;
```

Output: